# Image cropper (ngImgCrop) is not working inside ui modal in deviec or ios

Tags: ios, angularjs

I am having issue with `ngImgCrp` and in desktop it is working fine but not working in device/ios.

When I am clicking on input type file it is not working in mobile device or iOS. Can anyone suggest me what is the issue?
[Here](https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop) is the URL for plugin.